# xargs with rm + filename containing spaces

Tags: linux, shell, find, xargs

I am writing a simple programs which deletes all the fetched files. Files can contain spaces so I have added quotations as seen below

```
find -name "*.scala" | xargs -d "\n" -I {} rm \"{}\"
```

The above fails with error : cannot remove, no such file or dir. But if I list the same files they are there. Also if I do below and use bash to execute it; it works

```
find -name "*.scala" | xargs -d "\n" -I {} echo rm \"{}\" | bash
```

Can someone please explain why 1st scenario din't worked?

Comment: if you're using `find` use  `find ... -delete` instead. Piping to `rm` makes no sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
xargs -d "\n" -I {} rm \"{}\"
```

This assumes GNU coreutils' version of `xargs` that supports the `-d` option for specifying the delimiter.

This will not work together with your `find` command because it adds double quotes to the pathnames found by `find`. This means that instead of `./somedir/file.scala`, the call to `rm` is done with the literal pathname `"./somedir/file.scala"`.

Example:

```
$ touch hello
$ touch '"hello"'
$ ls
"hello" hello
$ echo hello | xargs -d "\n" -I {} rm \"{}\"
$ ls
hello
```

It works when you pipe the generated commands to `bash` because `bash` does quote removal.

It would probably also have worked if you didn't go through the extra effort to add the quotes in the first place:

```
xargs -d "\n" -I {} rm {}
```

---

To delete your files properly, use

```
find . -type f -name '*.scala' -delete
```

or, if you still want to use `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.scala' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

which passes the pathnames between `find` and `xargs` as a nul-delimited list. Nul (`\0`) is the *only* character that is not allowed in a pathname on Unix systems.  Filenames can additionally not contain `/`, but newlines are allowed.

A third option would be to call `rm` directly from `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.scala' -exec rm {} +
```

Note that `{}` does not need to be (and should not be) quoted as `find` knows perfectly well how to pass pathnames with spaces (or newlines or whatever it may be) to the named utility.

Comment: what does + do in : find . -type f -name '*.scala' -exec rm {} +

Comment: @linuxuser It means that as many as possible files will be given to `rm` at once.  If I had used `-exec rm {} \;`, I would have called `rm` once for each individual file. With `+`, the operation will be quicker since there will be less calls to `rm`.

Comment: Does it mean if find returns 5 files, by default xargs will execute the given command 5 times. But with + xargs will execute the given command only once

Comment: @linuxuser `-exec rm {} +` would execute `rm` once with five files, while `-exec rm {} \;` would execute `rm` five times with one file each time.

Comment: but the above definition is not limited to rm; its how exec argument will work for any command.

Comment: @linuxuser Yes, it's a feature of `find` and its `-exec`, not of `rm`. It would work similarly with any utility executed through `-exec`. Note that if you use `-exec utility {} +`, the `{}` must always come last before the `+` and the utility must support being called with multiple filenames.

Comment: W.r.t {} coming last before + statement ; so i cannot use something like -`exec echo {}"hello" +`. Can you give some examples which wont work to make me better understand ?

Comment: @linuxuser `-exec mv {} /destination +` for example.  With GNU `mv`, that may be written as `-exec mv -t /destination {} +` instead.